# subset data frame by complex pattern of column names

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

- two rounds of data (`.t0` and `.t1`)
- multiple scales (`this` and `that`)
- several items per scale (`1`, `22`, `22a`)
- several variables to ignore (`v2`, `v3`, `ignore.t0`, `ignore.t1`, `this.t0`, `this.t1`, `that.t0`, `that.t1`)

.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = seq(from=1, to=10, by=1),
                  v2 = rnorm(10),
                  v3 = rnorm(10),
                  ignore.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  this.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  this1.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  this22.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  this22a.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  that.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  that1.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  that22.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  that22a.t0 = rnorm(10),
                  ignore.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  this.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  this1.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  this22.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  this22a.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  that.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  that1.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  that22.t1 = rnorm(10),
                  that22a.t1 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to subset the data frame to include `id` and only columns with:

- the scale name (`this` or `that`) AND
- a number (`1.`) OR a number and letter (`22a.`) before the period

So in the end, the data frame should look like:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
                   id = seq(from=1, to=10, by=1),
                   #v2 = rnorm(10),
                   #v3 = rnorm(10),
                   #ignore.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   #this.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   this1.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   this22.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   this22a.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   #that.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   that1.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   that22.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   that22a.t0 = rnorm(10),
                   #ignore.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   #this.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   this1.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   this22.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   this22a.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   #that.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   that1.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   that22.t1 = rnorm(10),
                   that22a.t1 = rnorm(10))
```

The data frame is much bigger than what is represented here, so typing the column indices is not possible. It's also not possible to just look for the scale names because `this.t0`, `this.t1`, `that.t0`, and `that.t1` would be caught.

```
# not quite right
dat2$id <- dat$id
scales <- c("this", "that")
keep.index <- grep(paste(scales,collapse="|"), names(dat))
temp <- dat[keep.index]
dat2 <- cbind(dat2, temp)
```

How can I modify the grep pattern to look for a number OR (number and character) before the period? Or is there a better approach all together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for your example:

```
dat[c("id", grep("(this|that)\\d+[a-z]?\\.", names(dat), value = TRUE))]
```

where:

1. `\\d+` is for one or more digits
2. `[a-z]?` is for zero or one lowercase letter
3. `\\.` is for the dot

If you want to build a pattern dynamically for various `scales`, you can do:

```
scales <- c("this", "that")
pattern <- sprintf("(%s)\\d+[a-z]?\\.", paste(scales, collapse = "|"))
dat[c("id", grep(pattern, names(dat), value = TRUE))]
```

Comment: fantastic. the dynamic pattern is what i need. really helpful. i should be able to generalize from this example to other grep patterns. thanks!