# subset with pattern

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame df

```
df <- data.frame( a1 = 1:10, b1 = 2:11, c2 = 3:12 )
```

I wish to subset the columns, but with a pattern

```
df1 <- subset( df, select= (pattern = "1") )
```

To get

```
> df1
   a1 b1
1   1  2
2   2  3
3   3  4
4   4  5
5   5  6
6   6  7
7   7  8
8   8  9
9   9 10
10 10 11
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A related post is http://stackoverflow.com/q/19198492/429846

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to do this via

```
subset(df, select = grepl("1", names(df)))
```

For automating this as a function, one can use use `[` to do the subsetting. Couple that with one of R's regular expression functions and you have all you need.

By way of an example, here is a custom function implementing the ideas I mentioned above.

```
Subset <- function(df, pattern) {
  ind <- grepl(pattern, names(df))
  df[, ind]
}
```

Note this does not error checking etc and just relies upon `grepl` to return a logical vector indicating which columns match `pattern`, which is then passed to `[` to subset by columns. Applied to your `df` this gives:

```
> Subset(df, pattern = "1")
   a1 b1
1   1  2
2   2  3
3   3  4
4   4  5
5   5  6
6   6  7
7   7  8
8   8  9
9   9 10
10 10 11
```

Answer (score 2):

Base `R` now has a convenience function `endsWith()`:

```
subset(df, select = endsWith(names(df), "1"))
# or
df[endsWith(names(df), "1")]
```

In `data.table` you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("1")]
# Or more precisely
df[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("1$")]
```

In `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, ends_with("1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Same same but different:

```
df2 <- df[, grep("1", names(df))]
   a1 b1
1   1  2
2   2  3
3   3  4
4   4  5
5   5  6
6   6  7
7   7  8
8   8  9
9   9 10
10 10 11
```